# Shape behind text in windows store app

Tags: c#, background, windows-store-apps, shapes

I would like to have a shape behind the textblocks so that they appear like they belong together. Kind of like a groupbox except it will be a shape with color. Anybody knows how to do that? Or any way I can do this?

Comment: put the textblock in a container control like Grid and set the background color of the Grid to what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Grid` to contain shape & text block in it. Like given below. You can use `Rectangle`, `Ellipse` or `Path`.

```
<Grid>
    <Rectangle Height="25" Width="150" Fill="Red" />
    <TextBlock Text="Hello World!" FontSize="20" Width="150" />
</Grid>
```